# How to use ArrayBuffer and TypedArrays in Javascript without knowing length of buffer in advance?

Tags: javascript, arraybuffer, typed-arrays

Normally TypedArrays are initialized with a specific length passed to constructor They dont dynamically grow and dont allow appending more data once full. Since I am reading from stream, I am not sure how long my buffered data going to be. How to use TypedArray and ArrayBuffer without knowing the length of the data in advance?

Answer (score 0):

I think you still should have some kind of protocol there. I did similar kind of reading by defining smaller buffer that I used to read "pages" of data that I eventually combined. However I always asked first from the server that how many pages I should expect.